# MVC layout not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout

[layout working][1]My `GGW.cshtml` view code is

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GGW";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutYönetici.cshtml";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.ha</h2>
```

[layout working again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHPsG.png)
When I navigate to `localhost:20960/Yemek/GGW` its working.

But when I navigate to `localhost:20960/Yemek/GGW/` or `localhost:20960/Yemek/GGW/1`

the layout is not loading. Why?
[not working layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEBBT.png)

Comment: Please share the screenshot,if possible.

Comment: i addedd imageee

Comment: It might be possible some javascript error,Please open inspect element -> Console (You can open by pressing F12 key),and check whether there is any JS error or not ?

Comment: problem solved  <script src="../vendors/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>

deleted .. and working

Comment: Great,how did you find that problem ? by inspecting the console What I suggested to you do?